# Возможно ли с помощью Blazor WebAssembly создать браузерное приложение?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Появилась необходимость создать приложение, которое бы при нажатии на ярлык открывалось в браузере с помощью C#. Возможно ли это реализовать с помощью Blazor технологий? Что бы вы могли посоветовать?

Comment: 1. делаете веб сайтик как вам надо, 2. делаете экзешник какой-нибудь красивый который просто открывает браузер и редиректит на нужный сайт

Comment: [MAUI](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui)

Comment: @Aarnihauta а зачем экзешник-то тут? Ярлык можно и на веб-сайт сделать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov видимо я неправильно понял формулировку вопроса